# Function range() in Python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to understand what is the difference here? Is function range() better to be used here? Or why will we use range() if we cand do simply like (code #2)

Code 1:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    
for elem in range(len(a)):   
  print(elem)
```

Code 2:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]   
for elem in a:   
    print(elem, end=' ')
```

Comment: One prints the indices, the other prints the elements.

Comment: These do two different things.  Neither is “better”, because there are reasons to do either depending on the situation.  (You may want to check out `enumerate` which lets you do both in the same loop!)

Comment: More details are needed. Note that code 1 prints `0` through `4`  while the second example prints `1` through `5`. The difference is that the first example is the indexes of the list while the second example is the items in the list. Which is better? It depends on whether you want the indexes or the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short Answer

Both methods are valid ways to iterate over a list in Python, **but** they are used in different scenarios.

So the choice between the two methods depends on what you need to do with the list. If you only need the values and not the indices, the second method (`for elem in a`) is simpler and more idiomatic in Python. If you need the indices, the first method (`range(len(a))`) is appropriate.

Also as [@samwise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3799759/samwise) mentioned in the comments the `enumerate` function lets you work with both the indices and the values if you wanted.

### Additional Details

1. Using `range(len(a))` will give you the index of each element in the list. This is useful when you not only need the value of each element, but also its position in the list. In your example, `elem` will be the index of each element, not the element itself. You would use this method if you want to manipulate the list in place or if you need to know the index of each element for some reason.

   Code 1:

   ```py
   a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   for i in range(len(a)):
       print(i)
   ```

   This will print the indices (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) not the values of the list.
2. Using `for elem in a` will give you each element in the list directly. This is a more Pythonic way to iterate over a list when you don't need to know the index of each element. In your example, `elem` will be each element in the list.

   Code 2:

   ```py
   a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   for elem in a:
       print(elem, end=' ')
   ```

   This will print the values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Both the cases are valid and you can either of the cases but mostly these different approaches are used for indexing and picking an element within the list.

In the first step you applied you will only get the index but not the value.

In the second case you will the element but not the index.

Code1:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for elem in range(len(a)):
  print(elem)
```

The above code prints the indices.

If you want to print the elements:

Code 2:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for elem in a:   
  print(elem, end = '')
```

But this can be made easy by using list slicing:

```
print(a[::])
```

This will print all the values in the list.

But as our buddy @Curious has mentioned using the enumerate it can be done this way:

```
print(list(enumerate(a))
```

Output will be like this:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

It is good to use if you have string values in the list which makes them easy to identify.